# What time does a SQL query like this one start and end?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using a SQL query like:

```
SELECT * FROM game_list 
WHERE  start_date <= DATE(NOW()) AND end_date >= DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY game_id DESC;
```

Now, what time will this actually start and end? I mean I know on what date but what will the time be, is it midnight, 12 am, pm or what?

Comment: current time...24hours..and this will return you nothing

Comment: @Mr.Alien though it will still return values which satisfy this condition `start_date == end_date == DATE(NOW())`

Comment: actually i am trying to get only those games which are active within the period, say today is 6 and game has start date 7 and end date 10 so it should not be visible today (but what time it will be visible on 7 ?), but should be visible when 7 starts and should not be visible after 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly you want to show a game only if current time is between start time and end time,in that case what you need is actually:

```
SELECT * FROM game_list 
WHERE  DATE(NOW()) >= start_date AND DATE(NOW()) <= end_date 
ORDER BY game_id DESC;
```

This way it should work properly
The only problem i could see is if you don't format your start_date and end_date correctly.

- If your value is full time stamp,you should simply use NOW() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP directly as it contains both date AND time
- If your start_date is year month day eg: 2012-05-12 you should use CURDATE()
- If your value is simply a day number,like 1...2...3...4..etc you should use DAY()

I would doublecheck what start_date returns and decide accordingly,for reference i would take a look here [date and time in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: i am inserting simple mysql date as yyyy/mm/dd in start_date and end_date, my code is working perfectly, the problem is that i am not sure at what hours that condition starts to work in both start_date and end_date

Comment: midnight and 01 of both dates eg 2012-02-12 12:01,and will return true for the entire day untill 11:59..

Comment: so if you want to stop the query when end_date STARTS,eg midnight you should do end_date - 1
in that case your query should be 
SELECT * FROM game_list 
WHERE  start_date <= DATE(NOW()) AND DATE_SUB(end_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY); >= DATE(NOW())
ORDER BY game_id DESC;
this way your query stops at midnight of the day before end_date,which coresponds when end_date actualy starts,otherwise your query would include the WHOLE end_date

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how the `DATE` function works: it simply extracts the date part of a datetime.

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

```
SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
-> '2003-12-31
```

This represents simply that day. Considered as datetime again it would become midnight(2003-12-31 00:00:00)

Comment: I think he's asking how comparisons between datetimes and dates work. If you have a datetime '2003-12-31 01:02:03' and you compare it to the date '2003-12-31', which comparisons will be true?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like following

```
SELECT * FROM game_list 
WHERE  start_date <= DATE(NOW()) AND end_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY game_id DESC;
```

Above query fetch the records which starts before today and having end date greater than tomorrow's date